# Hide cPanel login page?

Tags: .htaccess

I use the url http://example.org/cpanel to log in.

This is accessible to anyone which seems like a bad idea as anyone can guess it's there. How can I hide it and make it accessible via .htaccess only to my IP address, or perhaps rename it so no one will find it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

adding a htaccess to only allow by ip can be done by this:

```
AuthName "My Secret Area"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.2.3.4
allow from .some.domain.org
</Limit>
```

Comment: Thanks! A couple of follow-up questions. What does `AuthName` do? What is the line `allow from .some.domain.org`?

Comment: Authname is the Htaccess message, it's just a message nothing special. The allow from .some.domain.org is if you want to allow people from a certain domain (multiple IP's with the same reverse lookup).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will implement this and see that it works as planned and then accept your answer.